# How can I make changes to the document show up while a function is running?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a project running with browser-side JavaScript and HTML.

I have a button that causes a computation-heavy function to run, which could take minutes to run. I run the function from the button like this: `` <button onclick=`longFunction()`>run</button> ``.

While the function is running, the page is inactive, and the only way I have found to provide data during the function running is `console.log()`, which is not ideal, since I want to show progress in the task while it's running (i.e. show percentage completed of the function).

I tried to find some method to refresh the screen so that the changes I made through setting `innerHTML` show up while the function is running, but I couldn't find anything.

Is there any such method? And what would you recommend generally in this scenario?

Comment: If you refresh the screen while your function is running, the function execution will immediately be halted. The best way to fix your problem would be to optimise your long running function so that it's not so computationally heavy, or to find another way to do whatever it is you need.

Comment: I meant that i want the updates i made to the document to show up

Comment: What is your function doing? Typical approaches are to break the computation into small chunks, separated by calls to setTimeout, or move it to a webworker

Comment: basically calculating the best move for a chess engine

Comment: K. Since that doesn't require any interaction with the dom, a web worker may be a good fit. I'm afraid that topic is a bit to complex for me to write up a full suggestion as an answer, but you can find tutorials and examples online.

Comment: i had tried looking into that, however i want to be able to run without a server, and based on what I saw, I can't do that.

Comment: web workers are entirely in the browser, no server involved.